# React setstate and array filter issue

Tags: reactjs, array-filter

I have a handledragover event, from where I am calling a function to remove an item from an array.The following is my code

```
function handleDragOver(e) {
    const { active, over } = e
if (over.id === "trash") {
      console.log("I am in trash");
      removeItemFromCanvas(active.id);
    }
}

const removeItemFromCanvas = (itemId) => {
    console.log(itemId);

    setCanvasItems((prevItems) =>
      prevItems.filter((item) => item.instanceId !== itemId)
    );
  };

My console log for item id is 1685584897944 and my array items are 
{id: 3, name: 'Item 3', instanceId: 1685584897944}
{id: 2, name: 'Item 2', instanceId: 1685585098521}
{id: 1, name: 'Item 1', instanceId: 1685585099515}
```

Though the first item is not matching, the array with the same elements are returned without filtering. Please help

Comment: Can you please add the code from where you are calling the handleDragOver method?

Comment: yes, can you show the full implementation of `setCanvasItems`